# Getting error EACCES while running npm run dev

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, yarn-lock.json

ritankarroy@Snehas-MacBook-Pro booblu % npm run dev

> booblu@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

- ready started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/ritankarroy/next/booblu/.next'] {
  type: 'Error',
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/Users/ritankarroy/next/booblu/.next'
  }

Tried to host the localhost and its showing error